# Які існують ресурси та онлайн-курси для вивчення української мови?

Tags: resource-request, вивчення-мови

Якими ресурсами, онлайн курсами, групами в соціальних мережах можна користуватися для вивчення української мови та її покращення?

Я можу назвати такі джерела та мобільні додатки:

1. [Онлайн курс "Лайфлаки з української мови"](https://courses.ed-era.com/courses/Osvitoria_and_EdEra/lifehacks101/lifehacks101/about) (анонснований 09.02.2017).
2. [Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/), проект в [pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/irinaaltair/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/), [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/mova.ukr), [вконтакті](https://vk.com/mova_ukrainian), [google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/104269744135702199629/posts), [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1061415385), [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ukr.mova).
3. Львівська ґвара (1000 слів) (Lviv subdialect of Ukrainian) для [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/ua/app/vivs-ka-gvara-1000-sliv-lviv/id1052791706?mt=8) - словних львівського говору.
4. [Р.І.Д.](http://www.rid.ck.ua/) створений для покращення та поглиблення знань української мови і культури на теренах країни та поза її межами. Версії для [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/r.i.d./id1159722844), [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ua.rid).

Comment: Мені подобається проект "Словотвір". Іноді не можу натішитися від знайдених слів. http://slovotvir.org.ua/

Comment: До тих хто голосує за закриття запитання: обговорення - чи потрібно дозволяти питання про ресурси: http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/30/do-we-allow-ask-for-resource-questions-%D0%A7%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%94%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83

Comment: sashaeve, зайдіть, будь ласка, на [meta](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com). Там зокрема є [wiki-питання зі списком онлайн-ресурсів](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/8/4) та [обговорення щодо того, чи треба виносити цей вікі-список сюди, на основний сайт](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/40/4). Станом на даний момент, тут, на основному сайті дозволені якісь конкретизовані питання щодо ресурсів (типу, [такого](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/101/4)), але не питання «які взагалі ресурси».

Comment: @Sasha, я знаю, що такі питання завжди знаходяться в "зоні ризику". Проте не можу погодитись, що таких питань немає. На SO є безліч питань на кшталт "які CMS на .NET/PHP ви знаєте" чи "які NER для української мови ви знаєте". Крім того, були питання з позначкою "community wiki", що означало, що питання не є питанням по суті, а набором порад чи посилань. На мій погляд, каталог ресурсів для вивчення є важливим, проте якщо питання порушує правила, то погоджуюсь, що його потрібно закривати.

Answer (score 4):

Для людей, що вивчають українську мову як іноземну, Duolingo.com має дуже непоганий початковий курс: [Learn Ukrainian Online](https://www.duolingo.com/course/uk/en/Learn-Ukrainian-Online)

Comment: [Memrise](http://www.memrise.com) -- схожа платформа.

Comment: професор Колумбійського університету США Юрій Шевчук написав книжку 
'Beginner’s Ukrainian with Interactive Online Workbook' http://www.hippocrenebooks.com/beginners-ukrainian.html